# Is possible to win a game of Yankee Doodle in the Vita version of the game? (touchpad usage)

Tags: ps-vita, project-diva-f-2nd

On the PS3 version of Project Diva f 2nd, you play Yankee Doodle by moving the analog sticks and pressing L3/R3 when required. On the Vita version, you have to slide or tap the screen which makes it almost impossible due to the speed on levels 2 and 3.

Is possible to win a game of Yankee Doodle in the Vita version of the game? If so, Does it requires a specific trick or something like that?

Comment: Sorry if the question sounds stupid, but I have been trying to get the "Call it Macaroni" trophy for months (it requires a win in Yankee Doodle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple trick that can be used to easily win rounds 2 and 3 versus any character as long as you don't miss.

You just need to ignore all of the swipe input and just tap the dots. Just tapping the dots will give you 4 bars and a half, which is over the minimum required to win each round (4 bars required).